# how to create a regex to validate with not more than one period

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex which will validate  the username of facebook,linkedin,twitter,instagram

for example :

```
sample.go - match
sample891 - match
@sample91 - match
sample91/c - no match
www.sample.go - no match
```

Currently i am using : `[-a-zA-Z0-9_@.\-]`

this is not working for double period . can some please help me . thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the period out of the character set. Then match anything in the character set, followed by an optional period, followed by anything in the set.

Also anchor it so you're testing the entire input string.

```
^[\w@\-]*\.?[\w@\-]*$
```

You can use `\w` as a shorthand for `a-zA-Z0-9_`, and there's no need to have `-` twice.